Use Buttons in HTML page to open different Iframes
I want to use the same script from different input buttons on the page, loading different iframes.
I am able to pass the Button Id and the Button Value to the function.
BUT how do I pass the Frame Name to the function?
My code is working but only for one iframe named "frame1":
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Grindarna" id="myButton1" onClick="changetext('myButton1','Grindarna','frame1')">
<div class="iframes">
  <iframe name="frame1" allowfullscreen style="display: none" frameborder="1" height="230" width=700px src="../texter/byggnader-herrgarden-info.htm" target="_blank"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
function changetext(Butto, KnappText, FrameN) 
{
var elem = document.getElementById(Butto);
if (elem.value==KnappText)
    { 
    elem.value = "Stäng";
    const el = document.querySelector('.iframes [name=frame1]');
    el.style.display = el.style.display === 'block' ? '' : 'block';
    }
else
    {
    elem.value = KnappText;
    const el = document.querySelector('.iframes [name=frame1]');
    el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
    }
}
</script>


Save space and use one <iframe> that multiple <a>nchors can open. For each link assign a different url to their href and assign the <iframe> name to each link's target attribute.
<a hfre="https://example.com" target="frame">EXAMPLE</a>

<iframe name="frame"></iframe>



<a href="https://example.com" target="frame">EXAMPLE</a>

<a href="https://m.google.com/" target="frame">GOOGLE - MOBILE</a>

<a href="https://www.amp-what.com/" target="frame">AMP-WHAT</a>

<iframe name="frame"></iframe>




I need a separate button for each separate iframe. They are on different places of the page.
I want to use the same script for them all. How can I pass the Frame name to the script?

I wouldn't use that script it's badly written. I'd  refactor it so the "click" event is delegated so no matter how many buttons there are everything goes through one function and one parent element even if there are buttons that are dynamically added later on.
